# How can I have only one div shown at a time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, slideshow, accordion

I have this code but I'm not sure how to make it so that each time one button is clicked, it closes the other div that is already open. New to jquery!

```
HTML:
    <p class="profile-name">Name</p><br>
                <p class="profile-title">Documentation Officer</p><br>
                <button id="button-g" class="bio-button">Bio</button><br>
                <a class="profile-email" href="mailto:email@test.com">email@test.com</a>
                <div class="toggler">
                  <div id="effect-g" class="profile-bio">
                      <p>Bio information. Bio Information</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

JQUERY:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#button-a" ).click(function() {
      $( "#effect-a" ).slideToggle( "visible");
    });
    $( "#button-b" ).click(function() {
      $( "#effect-b" ).slideToggle( "visible");
    });
    $( "#button-c" ).click(function() {
      $( "#effect-c" ).slideToggle( "visible");
        $("#button-b").hide();
    });
    $( "#button-d" ).click(function() {
      $( "#effect-d" ).slideToggle( "visible");
    });
    $( "#button-e" ).click(function() {
      $( "#effect-e" ).slideToggle( "visible");
    });
    $( "#button-f" ).click(function() {
      $( "#effect-f" ).slideToggle( "visible");
    });
    $( "#button-g" ).click(function() {
      $( "#effect-g" ).slideToggle( "visible");
    });
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: This is known as an "accordion" effect. Search that if you'd like to learn more.

Answer (score 5):

It's rarely wise to target a zillion elements by ID (or any other unique attribute) in a uniform, repetitive structure. Give all your buttons and all your collapsible siblings the same classes, respectively, then do this (or something similar--I can't be more specific without seeing your HTML):

```
$('.my-button-class').click(function() {
    $(this).next('.my-collapsible-div-class').slideDown()
      .siblings('.my-collapsible-div-class').slideUp();
});
```

This assumes markup like this:

```
<button class="my-button-class">Button</button>
<div class="my-collapsible-div-class"> ... </div>

<button class="my-button-class">Button</button>
<div class="my-collapsible-div-class"> ... </div>

<button class="my-button-class">Button</button>
<div class="my-collapsible-div-class"> ... </div>
```

---

Update based on your HTML:

```
$('.bio-button').click(function () {
    $(this).nextAll('.toggler:first').slideToggle()
        .siblings('.toggler').slideUp();
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/fzbuz6un/)**

- http://api.jquery.com/nextall
- http://api.jquery.com/first-selector

Off-topic suggestion: Use CSS margin or padding rather than line breaks to format your content. Extra markup elements for spacing is ugly and inefficient.

Comment: nice one, easy and short.

Comment: I tried this and for some reason it didn't work. I think I'm doing something wrong. I have updated my code with my html now.

Comment: When I use the code above like so:

(function() {
   $('.bio-button').click(function() {
       $(this).next('.visible').slideDown()
         .siblings('.visible').slideUp();
   });
     });

I can't even get the button to slide down. When I click on the bio button nothing happens now

Comment: Regarding your comment, well-designed logic precludes the need to check visibility of elements. Notice that neither of my examples do that.

Answer (score 1):

Give the div's a common class, and a custom data attribute with the letter of the next div to open, then combine this into a single function. Sample div:

```
<div id="effect-a" class="effect"></div>
```

Sample button

```
<button id="button-a" class="button" data-letter="a">Click me</button>
```

Single function

```
$(".button").click(function() {
    //Slide up any open divs
    $(".effect").slideUp();

    var divLetter = $(this).data("letter") //a

    //Concatenate selector
    $("#effect-" + divLetter).slideDown();
});
```